# AS3 AIR - addEventListener that is in effect when the window is not in focus

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, focus, addeventlistener

this is with Flash cs6 trying to make an air app.

Hi, I'm fairly sure this is easy to answer when you know the expression.

so I want to know how to detect a KEY_DOWN and KEY_UP when the window is out of focus.

```
var winkeyDown:Boolean = false;
var altkeyDown:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyisDown);
stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyisUp);
function keyisDown(e){

    trace(e.keyCode)
    if(e.keyCode == 91){
        winkeyDown = true
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 15){
        altkeyDown = true
    }
    if(winkeyDown && altkeyDown){
        stage.nativeWindow.activate()
        trace(stage.nativeWindow.x)
    }
}

function keyisUp(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 91){
        winkeyDown = false
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 15){
        altkeyDown = false
    }
}
```

this only trace e.keyCode when the window is in focus.

This is obviously because of `stage.` but I've been searching around for hours and can only find stuff about how to force focus and text field focus and such.

what should I use for it to detect what key is down when the window isn't in focus?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that due to security issues. Adobe wouldn't want people to do a key logger with AIR, it would be bad PR.

Comment: You cannot, as keyboard sends events only to OS-focused object, and if `stage` is not focused, this means the application is in background, thus will not be aware of keyboard events by OS design.

Comment: Could I maybe make an invisible window that activated every second and when it is activated it will check if those two keys are held down?
and if so, can I call the main window from the invisible window?

Comment: You may do that but the application the user wants to use the keyboard for won't get the focus.